# pip disappeared for some reason

Tags: terminal, homebrew, python

`pip` was fine but today when I tried to use it, I got this message:

```
-bash: pip: command not found
```

That's weird. `brew` shows that the `python` package from `brew` is still installed but now typing `python` in the terminal will run the one by default on the system instead:

```
~: brew install python
Warning: python 2.7.13_1 is already installed

~: python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15)
```

Trying to import the packages I had didn't work as well:

```
~: python
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2
>>> import PIL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

If I go into `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`, everything seems fine. Strangely it also work if I type

```
~: pip2 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
~: python2
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jul 18 2017, 09:17:00) 
>>> import cv2
>>>
```

What I can do to get `pip` (and my packages) back?

Comment: Python 2.7.10 is the system's Python (`~: python`), python 2.7.13 is the Python installed with brew!

Comment: @klanomath Yes I know. I don't know what happened but I used to be able to start brew's python by just typing `python` in the terminal.

Comment: What do you get if you type 'which pip'.

Comment: @john A return code `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having read the discussion about why this Homebrew change took place and some of the linked issues, it seems to me that linking to "pip" and "python" as you did in your answer might confuse things in the future.  Instead I followed the suggestions in [these](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/2897/files) [two](https://github.com/ome/omero-install/pull/159/files) GH PRs (and it is confirmed as the correct solution [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/15746#issuecomment-316292316)).

Edit ~/.bashrc to contain:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

I am using virtualenvwrapper and I also [needed to edit ~/.bash_profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199360/error-message-for-virtualenvwrapper-on-os-x-lion) to contain a similar line:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python
```

Comment: I had to add it in `~/.bash_profile` because bash doesn't use `~/.bashrc` for whatever the reason is.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that the reason these symlinks changed was due to the homebrew updates [announced](https://brew.sh/2017/07/31/homebrew-1.3.0/) in version 1.3.0:

> "The most significant change since 1.2.0 is that brew install python
>   no longer installs a python binary without manual PATH additions and
>   instead installs a python2 binary. This avoids overriding the system
>   python binary by default when installing Python as a dependency. It
>   also paves the way to eventually have python be Python 3.x."

Comment: Digging into it a little deeper turns up this discussion https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/14408

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by manually adding the symlinks back:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
ln -s python2 python
ln -s pip2 pip
```

However I still do not know why they disappeared in the first place.